# When using property on createCriteria can be returned as object?

Tags: grails

Why when I'm using `property()` on `createCriteria` returns me a list instead of object? If don't put `property()` gives me entire object but not a list?. `[[1, 'John', 'Tusk'],[2, 'Nila','Hans'],...]`

```
def employees = User.createCriteria().list{
    ...
    projections{
        property("id")
        property("pd.firstName")
        property("pd.lastName")
    } 
}
def results = []
employees.each{
    results <<  [id: it[0], name: it[1] + " " + it[2]]
}
```

Instead of using `employees.each`, theres another way to get like this to render as JSON:

```
[{"id":10,"name":"Erik Tucker"},{"id":83,"name":"Jimmy Sun"},..]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is within the documentation itself.

> A projection is used to change the nature of the results.

When a projection is used the results become a `list` of `list`s containing the values of the projected properties and not a list of matching object instances. This is by design and is [documented](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html).

Your approach, using `each`, is perfectly acceptable. All though, I would personally use `collect`, but the results are the same.